# Given 7 sales reps and 9 technicians, in how many ways can we choose 2 employees such that we have at least 1 sales rep?

Tags: combinatorics

> A company employs 7 sales representatives and 9 technicians. In how many ways can the company select 2 of these employees to send to a computer conference if at least 1 sales representative must attend the conference.

How to get the following answer???
Ans:84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

- 1 technician and 1 salesman - ${1\choose7}\cdot {1\choose9}$
- 2 salesmen - ${2\choose7}$

now summing them up youll get the answer

Answer (score -1):

they may send one tech and one sales rep in $9\cdot 7 = 63$ ways,
or two sales reps $\binom{7}{2} = 21$ ways.  Add those up.

Answer (score -1):

There are two kinds of teams:

a) Teams with 1 sales rep and 1 technician. There are $7\cdot 9 = 63$ of those.

b) Teams with 2 sales representatives. There are ${7 \choose 2} = 21$.

Adding these two numbers you get 84.

Answer (score -1):

Total possible ways: $16\times 15/2$. Number of possible ways with no salesman selected: $9\times8/2$. So, number of ways the team has at least on salesman = 120-36 = 84.